# The window.onload event is not firing in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I stripped down this javascript to be as simple as possible, and it's still not working in IE8.

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload !== 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    };
  }
}

function callkits() {
    alert('Kits: Bug testing');
}

//addLoadEvent(callkits);
//window.onload = callkits;
window.onload = function() {
    callkits();
};
```

Neither of the two commented out methods, nor the active method, do anything in IE8. Javascript is enabled. (Calling `alert` directly, outside a function, does work.) I'm tearing my hair out here.

**Edit:**

Okay, it's now even simpler:

```
alert('Before onload.')

window.onload = function() {
    alert('Onload');
};

alert('After onload');
```

In Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome, I get "Before onload", "After onload", then the page appears, then "Onload". In IE8, that last step doesn't happen. `window.onload` simply isn't firing.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8 (Win7 64)

Comment: I have found IE can be wonky when it comes to the onload event.  Are you using a framework?  I switched to use YUI's onDOMReadyEvent and it worked fine for me.  If your using any framework I imagine they have something similar.  I see nothing wrong with your code, I think IE is just acting up.

Comment: Doesn't work strangely indeed. It does work with jQuery though: http://jsfiddle.net/7VcHP/. Your code doesn't even work in Chrome, that's weird. I stripped it down to the minimal version and it's not working in Chrome, neither in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/7VcHP/2/.

Comment: You have to take the code out of the onload that comes standard with each code entry (change it to no wrap) code works http://jsfiddle.net/7VcHP/3/

Comment: Okay, it's working when there are no other javascripts on the page. Something else must be interfering. I'll dig.

Comment: I've found the answer. It was another script which was not called through the standard onload handler interfering. `<script for="window" event="onload" defer="1">products.related();</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard onload event won't work if another script is called using an HTML `defer` command.

`<script for="window" event="onload" defer="1">products.related();</script>`

Changing the above to use the standard `addLoadEvent()` function made it work.