# Problems with JavaScript and IE

Tags: javascript

I made a code that make a div follow the mouse on the window navigator, here is the code:

```
      <script type='text/javascript'>
     window.onload = function()
     {
        window.onmousemove = function(event)
        {
           var evento = event || window.event;

           var bloque = document.getElementById('x');
           bloque.style.top = evento.clientY+'px';
           bloque.style.left = evento.clientX+'px';

        }
     }
  </script>
```

BLOQUE

It works on firefox but it does not on IE. It simply does not do anything. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Im testing it on IE 8 by the way

Comment: I have just discovered that this code:

<script type='text/javascript'>
     window.onload = function()
     {
        window.onmousemove = function(event)
        {
          alert('click');

        }
     }
  </script>
Does not work on IE either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/0;

if (isMSIE) {
  // do IE-specific things
  bloque.style.top = window.event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop+"px";
  bloque.style.left = window.event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft + document.body.scrollLeft+"px";

} else {
  // do non IE-specific things
  bloque.style.top = event.clientY + window.scrollY+"px";
  bloque.style.left = event.clientX + window.scrollX+"px";

}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer, btu that does not work. Besides, I have alredy solved the event compatibility issue with:
var evento = event || window.event;

Comment: Nope, that does not work. By the way, I was trying to just open an alert window inside the onmousemove event on the anonymus function, but that does not work on IE8 either

Comment: If I change window.onmousemove for document.onmousemove it works finally on IE8. But why cant I use the window object on IE??

Comment: window.onload() fires before the page and its element are loaded, that might be causing some issues with javascript. this link examples the problem in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168022/the-window-onload-event-is-not-firing-in-ie8